# unexpected character at line 1 column 1

Tags: python, html, docker

I have a docker container serving a simple python application. When I curl, I get the right response as expected:
However when I browse via localhost:5000 I get the error as in the image attached. What am I doing wrong? [image]

Comment: Please don't upload your code as an image. Include it in your question using Markdown.

Comment: Just a wild guess but maybe your file is encoded in UTF-8 with leading BOM character (Byte Order Mark to determine Big vs Little Indian order). If that is the case then usual solution is saving your file (or changing project settings) to use UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: @Andy this error message thats why

Comment: You're missing lots of `<` characters at the beginning of each line. But I suspect that's because you didn't capture the whole window in your screenshot. Now do you understand why you should post text instead?